# A,B,P are three points on a circle having centre O. If angle OAP=25 and angle OBP=35 , then the measure of angle AOB is???

Tags: trigonometry, circles

A,B,P are three points on a circle having centre O. If angle OAP=25 and angle OBP=35 , then the measure of angle AOB is???

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: aob=120 ahh.i want the diagram

Comment: Err, is the image not visible?